# How to load multiple views inside side menu ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I want to display categories and sub categories inside a side menu. Instead of the menu displaying as an accordion like menu, I want to load sub categories in a  view which should load inside the side menu with back button. Is it possible to achieve in ionic 2?

First level of menu

[image]

Second level of menu

[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of your menu what you need?

Comment: So you want the sub categories to replace the categories and a back button takes back you to the parent categories? If so, that is entirely possible. It's just another view. If you know how to transition between views, you should be able to achieve this by passing the correct parameters to the sub category view.

Comment: Hi @Sampath, its like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/fpCyl

Comment: Hi @seesharper, I would like to load the sub category view inside side menu itself..

Comment: I don't understand people putting this question to HOLD as the question is quite clear, There is also link of example in comments. I also tried editing question and adding that link in question and got rejected.

Comment: And how about the code you've already tried ? Looks like @SenthilKumar gave the solution himself ..

Comment: @JoeriShoeby That is for angular 1 and is not suitable for ionic 2 which is based on angular 4

Comment: @SenthilKumar I have an answer for this , hopefully the question will be taken out of hold. But basically what you need to do is create components and not "pages". And then add those components to the `ion-menu` in your `app.html` in the place were you normally have the menu. You can then control the functionality with `Output() onClicks  = new EventEmitter()` which can then pass action to the `app.module.ts` and control the menu in there

Comment: @arkade Okay, so replace all ng-if for *ngIf and you're done. Can't understand why this should be a big issue ?

Comment: @JoeriShoeby thats funny, i take it you have not used angular 2+

Comment: @arkade What are you talking about Angular 2 ? Question poster is asking about Ionic 2, which could be translated 1:1 from Ionic 1.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Ionic 2 is built on top of angular 2+ , it is an angular mobile framework and there is no backwards compatibility to angular 1 or ionic 1

Comment: @arkade I'll agree, but with minimal programming skills you're able to translate the Ionic 1 features into Ionic 2.